# clicking a thumbnail image in galleria

Tags: galleria

I need to create separate pre, next, play and index count out of the current galleria and thumb containers.
I have worked out how to do the pre/next and play/pause but can not tie it into if a person clicks on the thumbnail image.
How do I bind the thumbnail being clicked to update the index count.

i.e.from 5/20 to 9/20 or whatever thumbnail was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image').click(function() {
        var current_index = $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image').index($(this)));
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

`Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.bind('thumbnail', function(e) {
        $(e.thumbTarget).parent().unbind('click').click(function() {
            $('#id_of_hidden_div').show();
        });
    });
});`